# When to use nil, blank, empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any guidelines on how to differentiate between `.nil?`, `.blank?` and `.empty?`?

I'm generally always confused as to when to use them in my application as they all seem to mean the same thing but have different meanings.

Does anyone have any cheat sheet on the gory details?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

- [**`nil?`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F) - checks to see if variable is referencing an object or not
- **`empty?`** - may be used to check on various object types like [empty string ""](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-empty-3F) or [empty array []](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F)
- [**`blank?`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) - checks for `nil?` or `empty?`.

Comment: String containing only "blank" characters is regarded as `blank?` but not `empty?`, e.g. "  \n \t"

Comment: Blank also returns true if the object has a value of false

Comment: I think the description for `nil` is inaccurate because `nil.nil?` is true, but `nil` is an object of `NilClass`.

Comment: if you are (a) not using Rails but (b) are using ActiveSupport, at least above some version (not sure which) ... and you need to include `blank?` only, here is how to cherry-pick just this one bit: `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank` ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html))

Answer (score 202):

Here I made this useful table with all the cases[image]

Comment: `nil.blank?` returns `undefined method` error. I use `object.to_s.empty?`. It returns `true` when the object is `nil` or `empty` string.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed `object.to_s.empty?` has one drawback when used in plain ruby - it raises `NameError` exception if object variable is not defined.

Answer (score 7):

- `nil?` is defined on all `Objects`, it only returns `true` on the `nil` singleton.
- `blank?` is defined on all objects too, it returns `true` if the object also responds to `empty?` and is empty, or is a `false` type value (`!object` is always `true`).
- `empty?` is defined on several collection objects, and is `true` if it has no elements. It is also defined on `String`.

note that `blank?` is `ActiveSupport` and not in *Rails 1.8*.

Answer (score 6):

I found a good explanation [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/160638):

> nil? tests whether the object is
>   exactly nil, that is whether it is the
>   one and only want instance of
>   NilClass.
>
> empty? is a method some objects
>   respond to. You need to check the
>   documentation for each case. For
>   example, and empty array is one that
>   is not nil (it is an array right?) and
>   has no elements. An empty string is
>   one that is not nil (it is a string
>   right?) and has no bytes, nothing.
>
> The blank? method you ask for does not
>   belong to Ruby, it is a Rails
>   extension:
>   http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/Object.html#M000011.

If you click through to the link at the end of that post you will find that the `blank?` method simply combines the `nil?` and `empty?` method calls.

Comment: `String containing only "blank" characters is regarded as blank? but not empty?, e.g. " \n \t"`, as [@xhh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654960/when-to-use-nil-blank-empty#comment21296385_1655001) wrote in another answer to this question.