# Understanding Rails validation: what does allow_blank do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm quite new to Rails and found a little snippet to validate presence and uniqueness step by step: first check presence, then check uniqueness.

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :allow_blank => true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

I'm a little bit confused about using `presence => true` and `allow_blank => true` together.

Without using `allow_blank => true` both rules will be checked at the same time and not step by step.

Why does `allow_blank => true` do this magic?

Comment: in the official guide it says ":allow_blank is ignored by the presence validator." Maybe this helps.

Comment: also have a look at [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1655001/1371131)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you've got is equivalent to this (wrapped for clarity):

```
validates :email, :presence => true, 
            :uniqueness => { :allow_blank => true, :case_sensitive => false }
```

That's a little silly though since if you're requiring presence, then that's going to "invalidate" the `:allow_blank` clause to `:uniqueness`.

It makes more sense when you switch to using other validators.. say... `format` and `uniqueness`, but you don't want any checks if it's blank.  In this case, adding a "globally applied" `:allow_blank` makes more sense and DRY's up the code a little bit.

This...

```
validates :email, :format => {:allow_blank => true, ...}, 
                  :uniqueness => {:allow_blank => true, ...}
```

can be written like:

```
validates :email, :allow_blank => true, :format => {...}, :uniqueness => {...}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just found this snippet somewhere on stackoverflow and became curious why someone should use `allow_blank` and `presence` together :)

Comment: you might want to use them together to display a different error message for invalid format vs blank for example. If you don't put the allow_blank you'd get an "invalid format" for a blank value

Answer (score 32):

The following distinction can be useful to know:

```
presence: true                    # nil and empty string fail validation
presence: true, allow_blank: true # nil fails validation, empty string passes
```

Comment: Is that acutally true? As far as I understand the docs, allow_blank will skip validations on all blank values. `nil` is a blank value. A quick test on Rails 5 tells me that `nil` does not fail my validation...

Comment: This answer is super WRONG! At least in Rails 5.

Comment: @dferrazm is correct here, you can see by looking at the tests for the presence validator with the `allow_blank` option: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0e626670476cb02a71a1bcb61f8b9d0b3315383f/activemodel/test/cases/validations/presence_validation_test.rb#L92-L106

Comment: Please edit the answer with corrections once you've verified in code what the behaviour is for how `presence` and `allow_blank` work together. I stopped using Rails many years ago otherwise I'd do it myself. I'm relying on the community to keep this answer up to date and reliable.

Comment: To make this work, use `validates :columnx, presence: true, if: Proc.new{ |x| x.columnx.nil? }`, based on https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

Answer (score 7):

`:allow_blank` is an option that will "disable" several of the validators, but not the presence validator.  The result of using these two together is that when the field is left blank, you will get the `:blank` error message (i.e., "can't be blank"), but not the other error messages.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `:presence =>` and `:uniqueness =>` are validators, while `:allow_blank =>` is a default option that gets passed to other validators.

So your code:

```rb
validates(
    :email,
    :presence => true,
    :allow_blank => true,
    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
)
```

Is equivalent to this code:

```rb
validates(
    :email,
    :presence => { :allow_blank => true },
    :uniqueness => { :allow_blank => true, :case_sensitive => false }
)
```

However, `presence` [is the opposite of](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.2/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb#L7) `blank`, so your code is actually equivalent to this code:

```rb
validates(
    :email,
    :uniqueness => { :allow_blank => true, :case_sensitive => false }
)
```

NOTE: In Rails v3 the `presence` validator ignored the `allow_blank` option (see [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_blank)).

I think what you really would want is this:

```rb
validates(
    :email,
    :presence,
    :uniqueness => { :allow_blank => true, :case_sensitive => false }
)
```

Having `:allow_blank => true` means that when the email is blank, the uniqueness validation will not be run.

One effect of this is that you eliminate a DB query.

E.g., *without* the `:allow_blank => true` condition you would see this:

```
>> user = User.new(email: nil)
>> user.valid?
  User Exists (0.2ms) SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" IS NULL LIMIT 1
=> false
>> user.errors.messages
=> {:email=>["can't be blank"]}
```

But *with* the `:allow_blank => true` option you won't see that `User Exists` DB query happen.

Another edge-case side effect happens when you *have* a record with a blank email address in your DB already.  In that case if you *don't* have the `:allow_blank => true` option on the `uniqueness` validator, then you'll see two errors come back:

```
>> user = User.new(email: nil)
>> user.valid?
  User Exists (0.2ms) SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" IS NULL LIMIT 1
=> false
>> user.errors.messages
=> {:email=>["has already been taken", "can't be blank"]}
```

But *with* the `:allow_blank => true` option you'll only see the `"can't be blank"` error (because the uniqueness validation won't run when the email is blank).

Comment: "the presence validator ignores the allow_blank option"

is this true?

Comment: @kuboon did you test it?

Comment: yes, I tested and read the code twice. allow_blank worked on PresenceValidator. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77582566/683157 .

Comment: thanks @kuboon, it looks like allow_blank ignored "presence" a long time ago (Rails v3) but has not for a long time. it now actually makes the "presence" validator a no-op. i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> from Rails annotation

```
# * <tt>:allow_nil</tt> - Skip validation if the attribute is +nil+.
# * <tt>:allow_blank</tt> - Skip validation if the attribute is blank.
```

so, it means when we use `allow_blank` on email, if the email is nil, only one error added to `errors` object, jump the uniqueness validates.

Answer (score 0):

Common options are distributed to each validators.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L94C1-L103C91

So your code:

```
validates(
    :email,
    :presence => true,
    :allow_blank => true,
    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
)
```

Is equivalent to this code:

```
validates(
    :email,
    :presence => { :allow_blank => true },
    :uniqueness => { :allow_blank => true, :case_sensitive => false }
)
```

In this case, [PresenceValidator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb) and [UniquenessValidator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb) receive these options.

Both do not override `EachValidator#validate` which process `allow_nil` `allow_blank` options.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activemodel/lib/active_model/validator.rb#L150C5-L157C8

```
    def validate(record)
      attributes.each do |attribute|
        value = record.read_attribute_for_validation(attribute)
        next if (value.nil? && options[:allow_nil]) || (value.blank? && options[:allow_blank])
        value = prepare_value_for_validation(value, record, attribute)
        validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      end
    end
```